# How reference a .lib file (native C++) in a Visual C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, static-libraries

I have a project in which I need to make a Visual C++ wrapper for a native C++ SDK, so that it can eventually be used in C#.

The SDK consists of .h files that I am correctly including (no compilation errors with these) and some .lib files which need to be referenced. And that seems to be the tricky part.

As I explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758851/unresolved-external-sybol-in-referenced-library-visual-c), I get errors whenever I try to call a function that's part of the library. The errors look like this:

```
error LNK2080: unresolved token (0A000027) "public: static class vhtIOConn *__clrcall vhtIOConn::getDefault(enum vhtICRConn::DeviceType)"
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class vhtIOConn * __clrcall vhtIOConn::getDefault(enum vhtIOConn::DeviceType)"
```

As I understand, C++/CLR expects `__clrdecl` while native C++ offers `__clrcall`.

What is the proper way to go about this? I have read in many places that this is possible, but I haven't seen any practical working examples. Note that I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Wow. I'm always amazed how superfluously overcomplicated yet broken Windows' ABI is. +1 because it must be a pain to get something like this working.

Comment: It is quite a pain indeed. I try to use this website as a last resort, but right now I simply don't have the slightest clue as to how to continue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really help you as - fortunately - I've never done Windows programming, but there are people around here who will have the answer for sure.

Comment: Why are you creating a Visual C++ wrapper when the wrapper itself could be written in C# by using PInvoke? As for the calling convention pick the one that applies to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell what's going wrong from the linker error, note the __clrcall in the error message.  That indicates that the compiler thinks that your native C++ is being compiled to MSIL, not to native code.  Which compiles just fine, any compliant C++03 code can be compiled to MSIL but dies when you try to link it.  You have to let it know, you can simply do so with a #pragma:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#   include "foo.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit further? 

In my example, I have a `MainForm.h` file, which includes a couple of Unmanaged C++ files. Let's just call those files `foo.h`. If I use the code that you posted, it gives a lot of `__clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code` errors, which makes me think it still treats `foo.h` as CLR code. I thought changing `managed` to `unmanaged` would help, but then it adds: `cannot compile unmanaged function with /clr:pure or /clr:safe` to all those instances.

Comment: There is nothing pure or safe about your code, you will need to compile with plain /clr.

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Thanks a lot! Now I'm puzzled as to why [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2008/09/03/extending-a-native-c-project-with-managed-code.aspx) website offers such a complicated solution... :)