# "error C2653: System is not a class or a namespace name" in Form header file, Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

My previous questions concerning the same project: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758851/unresolved-external-sybol-in-referenced-library-visual-c) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761567/how-reference-a-lib-file-native-c-in-a-visual-c-project). It's not necessary to read them; just know that I am trying to use a native C++ SDK in a Visual C++ project. This is much trickier than I had initially thought, but this website about [Extending a native C++ project with managed code](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2008/09/03/extending-a-native-c-project-with-managed-code.aspx) has helped me a lot further already.

As per that last link's instructions, I have added a Form to my native C++ project, which has automatically converted the project to a CLR one. Only `MainForm.cpp` and `Interface.cpp` (the file that allows native C++ code to create and show a MainForm) are compiled with the `/clr` flag though; the other files remain native.

The problem I have now, is that Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognise any of the CLR stuff that's being used in `MainForm.h`. As such, in the following lines:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

the word `System` is always underlined in red, with according errors:

```
error C2653: 'System' is not a class or a namespace name
```

for each of those lines.

It also does not recognise the word `gcnew` and other things that should work effortlessly inside CLR.

Can anybody tell me what I might be doing wrong? My guess is that it's something very small; some flag I have forgotten to change, a missing reference or something similar, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Where do you include `MainForm.h`? If you include it in any translation unit (i.e. \*.cpp) that is *not* compiled with `/clr`, then the compiler will of course complain about it, because `namespace System` and `gcnew` are not part of standard C++.

Comment: I include it in `Interface.h`. `Interface.cpp` is compiled with `/clr`, but as that third link in my post says, that should work.

Comment: Ok, where do you include `Interface.h`? Since you include `MainForm.h` in `Interface.h`, you include it indirectly anywhere where you include `Interface.h` as well. Maybe you should only include it in `Interface.cpp` and use forward declarations in `Interface.h`

Comment: Oh wow, that was it! I was including the `MainForm.h` in `Interface.h` instead of `Interface.cpp`. This isn't mentioned in the tutorial, but it's logical when you think about it... Thanks a lot. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept and upvote it. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you include `MainForm.h` - directly and indirectly?
If you include `MainForm.h` in `Interface.h`, you include it indirectly anywhere where you include `Interface.h` as well. That means, if you then include `Interface.h` in any translation unit (i.e. *.cpp) that is not compiled with `/clr`, then the compiler will of course complain about it, because `namespace System` and `gcnew` are not part of standard C++.

Therefore you should include `MainForm.h` only in `Interface.cpp` and use forward declarations in `Interface.h`.